# Assertions not compiled out of release build

Tags: visual-c++, release, assertion

I've told VC++ to compile my program in release mode, yet the assert() statements still fire.  I thought assertions were supposed to be compiled out of release builds for performance.  What's going on?  Is there some other setting I need to set skip compiling them?

Comment: Is there any difference in the assert message between debug and release?

Comment: Single or multiple module output?

Comment: i've tried rebuild all, didn't work.  It's multiple modules.

Comment: the assertion failed message is exactly the same for both modes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check which preprocessor symbold you're defining.  A Debug build would normally define `_DEBUG`, and a Release build would normally define `NDEBUG`.  Assertions would normally be switched off when `NDEBUG` is defined.

Comment: NDEBUG is set and _DEBUG isn't

Comment: ok this is interesting: in the main project, the one that has WinMain(), NDEBUG is defined and _DEBUG isn't.  But for all the other projects, it's the opposite, even though they are set to release mode.

Comment: Ok.  So I've merged all the files into one project for now, and it seems to fix the problem.  Still don't know why it the debug symbols were different for each project.

Answer (score 0):

Open the app under the debugger. Do debug->break when the assertion dialog is up. Look at the source file where the assert is firing. Now look at the build settings of that file. If the settings seem right and you are loading the release version, set /P and /d1PP on the compiler command line to reveal where the errant #define is coming from.

Martyn